# Chapter and Content like design in Android

Tags: android

I don't want this question to be fully opinion based. I just want to know **pros and cons of my approach and how to resolve all cons?**

**Goal**

I want to show chapters and when user clicks each chapter I need to make a call to my server and get the data and display it after parsing?

**My Approach**

I assume I will have around 100 chapters. I will have a menu like design at the top menubar. If user clicks menu button, chapters will be visible. When user clicks on a chapter, I will create a fragment to display the data.

**My problems**

1. Number of chapters - Mobile is a small device. If I display 100 chapters at a time via menu, it will not be user friendly.

   **My solution for the problem** - I will split the chapters and make an activity which will have list of grouped chapters. Like Chap1-10, Chap11-20 ..
     When user clicks on one chap group, I will create an activity and display only 10 chapters in menu. For each click, create a fragment within the new chap group activity.
2. Should I use activity or fragment for content display? Is there any alternative approach?
3. Should I query my server for each chapter click? Or shall I store data in Realm database? Is it safer? Safer in the sense can User access realm stored data?

Any suggestions? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use ExpandableListview in Navigation drawer to show chapter

Answer (score 0):

My opinion problemwise: 
1&3. 
Mobile is not a small device, to store 100 chapters, infact you can download 10 books and keep in device.Only that you have to store in form of json that too in nosql database. It will hardly be in MBs. As book is something end user will like to read even if its offline, you should give him a option of downloading it in wifi and store complete book. Use : http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-mobile

2: Display: 
Use navigation drawer with submenu for chapters
(http://www.technotalkative.com/part-4-playing-with-navigationview/)
and flipbook animation for pages
(https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip)

Comment: Thanks, It's online based. Not offline based to provide as a book. It has some other scenarios with chapters.

Comment: Even then i would recommend you to use the nosql and use a sync framework just like gmail/outlook.